# Best practice to include console app in NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget, console-application, .net-standard, multi-targeting

I'm developing an open-source library which mainly consists of one class-library project targeting .NET Standard 2.0. On top of that, I've also implemented a console app which is the CLI to this library. The console project (for historic reasons) only targets .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Now I wonder what would be the best practice in order to make this console app available to the community. On the broadest level, I see two possibilities:

1. Ship the console app as a separate NuGet.
2. Ship the console app in the same NuGet as the class library because it's just a minor add-on and does not justify an own package.

Historically, I've been using the second approach but considering that the class library can be used in a multi-targeting scenario, I'm not sure anymore. Maybe it's cleaner to separate the console app in a NuGet of its own so that it's dependency on the full .NET framework is clear.

Either way I wonder where the console exe belongs to in the file structure of the NuGet. Historically, I've been putting it under `tools\net462` but a comment about the `tools` folder on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory) made me insecure:

> Powershell scripts and programs accessible from the Package Manager Console

I'm not necessarily imagining someone using the CLI from the Package Manager Consoler. Rather it would be used as stand-alone exe somewhere is some shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [NuGet is meant only for delivering class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#deciding-which-assemblies-to-package) (note the wording "if your library...").

Use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) instead for deploying command-line and GUI apps to Windows. It has a CLI that can be used to easily install and update applications. It is **not** `NuGet`, but uses a similar method to package and deploy the app.

There are also package managers to target other platforms:

1. [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) (for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint)
2. [Brew](https://brew.sh/) (for MacOS)
3. [RPM](http://rpm.org/) (for Fedora/Red Hat)

> **NOTE:** As Martin Ullrich pointed out in the comments, there is now a [way to deploy build tool CLIs with NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility#per-project-based-extensibility), which is primarily meant for continuous integration deployment scenarios.

Comment: Interesting. However, visiting this page, the first thing I read is: "Chocolatey - The package manager for Windows". That excludes Linux/Mac, I guess? Which is the foremost reason I targeted .NET Standard.

Comment: @Dejan You should use whatever package managers exist for those platforms....apt-get, brew, rpm or whatever. NuGet should only be used to serve up class libraries.

Comment: @mason: that's an interesting comment: "NuGet should only be used to serve up class libraries." If this is true, then that answers my question. Can you back up this claim a little bit and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Dejan - Well, that only becomes a concern if you target .NET Core with your CLI app. But as mason mentioned, there are other package managers that can be used for other platforms.

Comment: @Dejan I don't have any firm statements from a well respected authority. People have varying opinions. For example [this Microsoft employee](http://mitchdenny.com/the-tyranny-of-nuget/) doesn't like using NuGet packages (.nupkg) for anything except class libraries. I have no object to the use of the .nupkg in Chocolatey or [Octopus](https://octopus.com/) or [PowerShellGet](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet). My concern is with polluting the NuGet repository (nuget.org) with packages that don't contain class libraries. The repository should have a single purpose.

Comment: @mason: I'm very glad you clarified this to me. I absolutely agree.

Comment: @Dejan If you're distributing to Windows, note also that [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps#APPX) is appropriate. Things seem to be moving (slowly) in that direction. UWP is built into Windows 10, supports console apps, and is easily distributed via download (just a .appx file) or the Windows Store. And it's the only way to get 3rd party programs onto (still rare) Windows 10 S.

Comment: If it is a true "tool" NuGet you can create a CLI tool package that can be added on a per-project basis. the upcoming 2.2.0 version of the CLI will also have "global" tools via `dotnet install tool`. Doc for per-project tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility#per-project-based-extensibility

Answer (score 6):

Ther is a solution that seems to fit your needs. You can create a command line extension for the `dotnet` tools. Like `dotnet ef` you can create a `dotnet myAwesomeTool` command. The only thing that you need to do is the Following:

Create a console application and add the following code to your .csproj

```
<PackageId>Company.MyAwesomeTool</PackageId>
<AssemblyName>dotnet-myAwesomeTool</AssemblyName>
<PackageType>DotnetCliTool</PackageType>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

Build the solution and you will find a nuget package in your bin folder. This nuget package can be distributed and when you have installed it, you can run `dotnet myAwesomeTool` in the projects where the nuget is installed. Works like a charm for me =)

To install it on other projects, add this to the csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="company.MyAwesomeTool" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="company.MyAwesomeTool" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For more infos:
https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/04/10/extending-dotnet-cli-with-custom-tools.html

Comment: This seems to fall down if the tool you built requires other (not-tool) nuget packages. (Error NU1212 on install)

Comment: I referenced a lot of "not tool" nuget packages to build the nuget tool and I did not get such an error. This was over a year ago, but I am pretty confident that it did not change until today. How would you build a nuget package without any other nuget package, lets say newtonsoft-json. I do not think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When time pass by, other solutions come available...

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create

```
<PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
<ToolCommandName>botsay</ToolCommandName>
<PackageOutputPath>./nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
```